Perché nessun logo originale?
Ispanoparlanti, francoparlanti, tedescoparlanti, giappoparlanti, angloparlanti. Tutti hanno inventato un logo per i loro siti. Perché ancora abbiamo il logo predefinito? ¡Media pila, gente! Se considerate lecita questa domanda, allora penserò alcune idee. ❤

Precisazione: lo sai già che non parlo italiano. Autorizzo qualsiasi ‘limatura’. PS: Creo che ‘Ispanoparlanti’ è la mia parola preferita.

Vabbe' dai tac! Dai qualche idea!

Ho aggiunto dei link ai siti. Segnalo che ci sono anche gli stack exchange di cinese, russo, latino, portoghese, coreano, ucraino, esperanto che hanno ancora il tema predefinito.

Convertito da un commento:

Purtroppo non dipende solo da noi - lo staff di SE decide chi riceve un logo e chi no :).


Non è soltanto il logo, ma l'intero stile del sito. Per quanto vedo, i nuovi siti non hanno ricevuto uno stile "unico", probabilmente perché è diventato dispendioso poterlo fare. (Il che non significa che in futuro il sito non possa ricevere uno stile tutto suo.

Come indicato in Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September! lo stile del sito (ed il suo logo) è cambiato quando il sito non è più un sito "beta", ma non avviene immediatamente. Dei 59 siti elencati in Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta, soltanto tre hanno avuto un nuovo stile.

Artificial Intelligence
Quantum Computing
Stack Overflow in Japanese

Stack Overflow in Japanese ha uno stile diverso dagli altri siti, ma è essenzialmente lo stesso di Stack Overflow.
Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta dice anche che, nel 2021, non si stava cambiando stile a nessun sito, ma che stavano facendo esperimenti su alternative a cambiare completamente stile di un sito. Nel frattempo, hanno reso più facile (per loro) cambiare stile ad un sito.
